# PHP Shopware Rest API - How to sum specific Keyvalues of Arrays in an Array

Tags: php, arrays, sum, shopware

I want to calculate and show the turnover of some webshops(Plattform:Shopware), filtered by month and without canceled orders.
I got the connection to the webshop, I already got all orders, sorted them by month, filtered out the canceled orders. Now I pushed all relevant orders into a new array called $october. In $october, every single order is an array itself with many keys and values. I just need to summarize all "invoiceAmount" values together so i can show the turnover of this month. I tried many variations(commented), the best i get is "0" from the initialization of $sum... but im also very new to php. please help me out :-)

[API Resources Orders](https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/api-resource-orders/)

```
<?php
include_once ('api.php');

$url = xxxxx;
$user = xxxxx;
$key = xxxxx;

$client = new ApiClient($url,$user,$key);
$orders = $client->get('orders');
$october = [];

echo "<h1>===================month Array==============</h1>";
foreach ($orders as $order) {           
    foreach ($order as $field) {
        if ($field["orderStatusId"]!==4) {

            $mystring = $field[orderTime];
            $findme   = '-10-';
            $pos = strpos($mystring, $findme);

            if ($pos !=null) {
              print_r($field);
              array_push($october,$field);
            } 
        }

    }
}

echo "<script>";
echo 'console.log('.json_encode($october).')';
echo "</script>";
print_r($october);

echo("<h1>===================Sum of month==============</h1>");

$sumOctober = 0; 
    foreach ($october as $field["invoiceAmount"]=>$value) {
        $sumOctober+= $value;
        }


/*
$sumOctober = 0; 
foreach ($october as $order) {
    foreach ($order as $field["invoiceAmount"]=>$value) {
        $sumOctober+= $value;

    }
}
*/
echo($sumOctober);

/*
$arr = $october;
$sum = 0;
foreach ($arr as $order){
    foreach ($order as $field["invoiceAmount"]=>$value) {
    $sum += $value;
}
}
*/

/*
$arr = $october($orders($key));
    $sum = 0;
    array_walk_recursive($arr, function($val, $key) use (&$sum) {
        $sum += $val;
    });
    var_dump($sum);
echo "<h1>Die Summe Oktober ist:</h1>";
echo ($sum);
*/
?>
```

[image: php answer in browser page 1]

[image: php answer in browser page 2]

[image: php answer in browser page 3]

[image: php answer in browser page 4]

[image: php answer in browser page 5]

Comment: Adding images of text is a sure way to not get any good attention to your question. Include text as text, arrays as arrays (var_export).

Answer (score 0):

This totally helped, dont know why the guy deleted his answer right away...but thanks!

```
$sumOctober = 0; 
foreach ($october as $oct) {
    $sumOctober+= $oct["invoiceAmount"];
}
```